# how replace text "CDATA"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, browser-cache

I have tried to replace the text of "CDATA" from item of `cachdescription` from below spider code:

```
item['CacheDescription']= response.xpath("//html").replace("CDATA" ,' ')
```

Output:

```
* <![CDATA[ */ function URLReplacePlus(strIn) { var a = "+"; var b = "%43"; var c = strIn; var i = c.indexOf(a); var l = b.length; while (i != -1) { c = c.substring(0,i) + b + c.substring(i + a.length,c.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) to get the actual string value:

```
response.xpath("//html").extract()[0].replace("CDATA" ,' ')
```